# Add a reminder to Android calendar in xamarin

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin

I am adding a reminder to a calendar entry. i am using this piece of code,

```
 ContentValues eventValues = new ContentValues();
            eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.CalendarId, _calId);
            eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Title, "Test Event");
            eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Description, "This is an event created for demo app");
            eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtstart, GetDateTimeMS(DateTime.Today, DateTime.Now));
            eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtend, GetDateTimeMS(DateTime.Today.AddDays(1), DateTime.Now));
            eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.HasAlarm, true);
            eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventTimezone, "Local");
            eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventEndTimezone, "Local");
            var eventUri = ContentResolver.Insert(CalendarContract.Events.ContentUri,
                                           eventValues);
            long eventID = long.Parse(eventUri.LastPathSegment);
            string reminderUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/reminders";
            ContentValues reminderValues = new ContentValues();
           // reminderValues.Put(CalendarContract.Reminders.InterfaceConsts.CalendarId, _calId);
            reminderValues.Put(CalendarContract.Reminders.InterfaceConsts.EventId, eventID);
            reminderValues.Put(CalendarContract.Reminders.InterfaceConsts.Method, RemindersMethod.Alert.ToString());
            reminderValues.Put(CalendarContract.Reminders.InterfaceConsts.Minutes, 5);
            Android.Net.Uri url = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(reminderUriString);
            var reminderUri = ContentResolver.Insert(url, reminderValues);
```

this doesnt give any exception but does not add the reminder either. what is wrong? How do i add reminder?i do have write permission. I am able to add calendar events but not able to add reminders

Answer (score 1):

RemindersMethod is an enum, so you need to cast it to an int.

So change your code for adding Reminder method to:

```
remindersValues.Put(
  CalendarContract.Reminders.InterfaceConsts.Method,
  (int) RemindersMethod.Alert
);
```